# How to use vtkThreshold (or more appropriated) to get point ids of points with coordinates in threshold

Tags: python, c++, grid, visualization, vtk

I'm whould like to know how to get a list of Ids for points with position in threshold. For example, I need a list of points that have x coordinate less than 1.

```
  idlist = []
  ncells = UnstructuredGrid.GetNumberOfCells()
  for idx in xrange(ncells):
        p = UnstructuredGrid.GetPoint(idx)
        #Check if x less them 1
        if p[0] < 1:
            idlist.append(idx)
```

I'm looking for a more efficient and smarter way of doing it. Probably there is a way using vtkUnstructuredGridFilter or vtkThresholdPoints.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no simpler way to iterate over this UnstructuredGrid, you could write a generator to make this kind of function more elegant.

```
def generate_grid():
  for id in xrange(UnstructuredGrid.GetNumberOfCells())
    yield UnstructuredGrid.GetPoint(idx)
```

Then you could use this in a list comprehension, e.g.

```
idlist = [point[0] for point in generate_grid() if point[0] < 1]
```

or a filter:

```
idlist = filter(lambda point: point[0] < 1, generate_grid())
```

Comment: I'm looking for a explanation on how to use vtk provided functionality to do the same.